# How to create "real" UITableView(Cell) margins where cells cannot be selected outside their content frame?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to create a `UITableView` layout where the table view itself fills the complete screen (-> scrollbars are shown at screen endges) but the cells are horizontally centered with a fixed width. It should only be possible to select a cell / tap on it within this fixed width but not within the margins:

Simply giving the `UITableView` and fixed with + center alignment does work, but in this case the scrollbars are not at the screen edges and it is not possible to scroll using the complete screen but only within the tableView frame.

I tried different other solutions:

```
let cellWidth = 200
let widthDiff = (tableView.frame.width - cellWidth) / 2

// Solution 1: Change horizontal content inset
tableView.contentInset.left = widthDiff
tableView.contentInset.rigth = widthDiff

// => Cells still use the complete width but can be scrolled horizontally by widthDiff 
// => Does NOT work


// Solution 2: Setting layout margins on tableView
tableView.layoutMargins.left = widthDiff
tableView.layoutMargins.rigth = widthDiff

// Solution 3: Setting layout margins on cells...
...
cell.layoutMargins.left = widthDiff
cell.layoutMargins.rigth = widthDiff

// Solution 4: Manually center the cell content using constraints within the cell layout.

// => Layout looks correct in all three cases, but while the cell content 
//    has the correct margins, the cells itselfs still use the complete 
//    screen width and is still possible to tap/select sells outside 
//    their frame.
// => Does NOT work
```

So, I was not able to find a solution which fulfills all three requirements:

- Fixed width, centered cells with left and right margins
- Scrollbars at screen edges / table view can be scrolled using the complete screen
- Cells can only be selected / tapped on within their content frame

**Is there a solution using `UITableView` properties and methods?**

---

EDIT: As requested this image shows what it should look like:

- Cells are centered in the middle with some margins on both sides
- Scrollbars are at the screen endge

**But:** The cells still occupy the complete width. When tapping in the area of the margins cell is still selected and its selected-background uses the complete width. This should be avoided.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some picture of UI that you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

From touches point of view you seem to want that cells are selectable only at specific position but table view can be selected everywhere where table view is (for scrolling).

From views point of view you wish to limit cells to specific location but want to draw table view everywhere (scrollbars at the edge).

Then I would say that table view needs to stretch through whole screen and the cell content should be limited. This would best be done with simply constraining a custom view within your cell. The selection of cells would then need to be custom. Consider something like the following:

(I intentionally did some parts programmatically to show what is being done. But I would put most of this in storyboard).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private var tableView: UITableView?
    
    var dataSource: [Bool] = []
    
    var cellWidth: CGFloat = 200.0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView?.allowsSelection = false
        dataSource = .init(repeating: false, count: 100)
        tableView?.reloadData()
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = MyCell()
        cell.setupIfNeeded(width: cellWidth)
        cell.isCellSelected = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        cell.onMiddleViewPressed = { [weak self, weak cell] in
            self?.dataSource[indexPath.row] = true
            cell?.isCellSelected = true
        }
        return cell
    }
    
}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    private var isSetup: Bool = false
    private var middleView: UIView?
    
    var onMiddleViewPressed: (() -> Void)?
    var isCellSelected: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            middleView?.backgroundColor = isCellSelected ? .blue : .gray
        }
    }
    
    func setupIfNeeded(width: CGFloat) {
        guard isSetup == false else { return }
        isSetup = true
        
        let middleView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        middleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(middleView)
        contentView.addConstraint(.init(item: middleView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
        middleView.addConstraint(.init(item: middleView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: width))
        contentView.addConstraint(.init(item: middleView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
        contentView.addConstraint(.init(item: middleView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
        
        middleView.backgroundColor = isCellSelected ? .blue : .gray
        
        middleView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onMiddleViewSelected)))
        self.middleView = middleView
    }
    
    @objc private func onMiddleViewSelected() {
        onMiddleViewPressed?()
    }
    
}
```

To create a toggle in selection you would then simply do:

```
cell.onMiddleViewPressed = { [weak self, weak cell] in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    self.dataSource[indexPath.row].toggle()
    cell?.isCellSelected = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]
}
```

To use a single selection you would do

```
cell.onMiddleViewPressed = { [weak self, weak cell, weak tableView] in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    if let currentSelectionIndex = self.dataSource.firstIndex(of: true), currentSelectionIndex != indexPath.row {
        self.dataSource[currentSelectionIndex] = false
        let targetIndexPath = IndexPath(row: currentSelectionIndex, section: 0)
        if tableView?.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.contains(targetIndexPath) == true {
            tableView?.reloadRows(at: [targetIndexPath], with: .none)
        }
    }
    self.dataSource[indexPath.row].toggle()
    cell?.isCellSelected = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]
}
```

so this is nothing too heavy. And a pretty standard procedures in cases like having `UISwitch` (or similar components) for selection where selecting the cell does something completely different (navigate to details for instance).

Perhaps you also need transparent cells and table view. This is just:

```
tableView?.backgroundColor = .clear

cell.backgroundColor = .clear
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
```